# What is a upper limit of the HTTP request in Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-413

I have read in GCP Cloud Function documentation that, max uncompressed HTTP request size should not be more than 10MB to HTTP Cloud Functions. But, when we are passing merely 200 KB JSON as an input which is consist of an image encoded in base-64 format, we are getting an error 413, Request Entity too large. Please find attached the error screenshot.
[screen shot for error 413](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqNRk.png).

Can anyone explain the reason behind that? And also remedy for that?

Comment: Can you share a minimal and reproductible piece of code?